# Creating a user session - NODE js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, session, express

I am new to node js & javascript in general. I have the below piece of code that will handle a login. I have a MYSQL database with a customer table. When the customer enters their username and password, it checks does it exist in the database. This part is working.

I now want to enhance this feature so that it will take the username and create some sort of a session variable, which can be used across the application. I am new to JS so I am not yet sure which inbuilt facilities already exist, or best practice around sessions.

I want to be able to use this session variable across the application, and for subsequent logout facility.

Can someone advise me on this, or point me in the right direction? Thanks.

case "/login":

```
var body = '';

console.log("user Login ");

request.on('data', function (data) {
    body += data;
});

request.on('end', function () {
    var obj = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Customer where name='"+obj.name+"'";
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });

    db.query(
        query,
        [],
        function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                response.end('{"error": "1"}');
                throw err;
            }
            if (rows!=null && rows.length>0) {
                console.log(" user in database" );
                theuserid = rows[0].customerID;
                var obj = {
                    id: theuserid
                }
                response.end(JSON.stringify(obj));

            }
            else{
                response.end('{"error": "1"}');
                console.log(" user not in database");
            }

        }
    );
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple ways of implementing a user session.

One, you could use a browser cookie, it comes with many pros and cons and you should read about it a bit to see how its managed. This would also depend on the server you are using (express, hapi, etc).

Two, you can set a JWT token on the backend, and include it in the header of the response, then you can either use your application state or the local storage of the browser to save that token on the UI. Any such follow up requests requiring authentication should contain this auth token as a header for verification.

For more clarity, you can look into related libraries (such as passport), which make this task a lot easier.

PS: If you choose cookies, please make sure the business is going to allow it or not as the end-users do not like being tracked always. :)